# Using geocoder on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, geocoding

I am developing a location based application. And i need a trustable source for getting geolocation.

right now i am using this [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) plugin.

and i am getting this error:-

```
Geocoding API not responding fast enough (see Geocoder::Configuration.timeout to set limit).
```

I am getting error when our team of 5 is testing on staging servers

I need a fast enough solution with some ~10k request a day with no per second limits

**PS: I am open to use some paid service.**

**EDIT**

Think of a case you want to search something in NewYork. In textbox you will type newyork and press enter. Now on server side I need to fetch geocode for newyork and then search in db based upon that.

Comment: Possible solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093393/geocoding-api-not-responding-fast-enough-for-ip-address

I hope this help you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should geocode client side (in javascript) you won't be hit by the limits :

> Server-side geocoding, through the
> Geocoding Web Service has a quota of
> 2,500 requests per IP per day, so all
> requests in one day count against the
> quota. In addition, the Web Service is
> rate-limited, so that requests that
> come in too quickly result in
> blocking. Client-side geocoding
> through the browser is rate limited
> per map session, so the geocoding is
> distributed across all your users and
> scales with your userbase. Geocoding
> quotas and rate limits drive the
> strategies outlined in this article.
>
> **When to Use Client-Side Geocoding**
>
> The basic answer is "almost always". As
> geocoding limits are per IP address,
> that limit counts against the consumer
> of your application. It's going to be
> very rare that someone is going to
> enter more than 2,500 addresses a day
> sitting at their computer. Therefore,
> running client-side geocoding, you
> generally don't have to worry about
> your quota.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/geocodestrat.html

Comment: I am not looking for maps dear. Think of a case you want to search something in NewYork. In textbox you will type newyork and press enter. Now on server side I need to fetch geocode for newyork and then search in db based upon that.

Comment: That's the point, you can geocode "new york" client side in javascript and send the google response in a hidden input of your form. I already dealt with this: it works and there's no api limits.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably bound to happen with any web based service.  You might want to consider sending these tasks to a background job manager (such as Resque or Delayed Job) which will retry failed jobs without disrupting users.  They also make your application seem faster since your user will not have to wait for third party (and possibly intermittent) web applications to respond.

Comment: but i need that in between. I cant pass it to delayed job.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [maxmind.com](http://maxmind.com) - this will do a geo lookup based on IP address. They have a free or paid for database that your store on your server. They have a [Ruby API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ruby). I use this in a production system and the lookups are typically sub-millisecond as the data is cached.