# Ruby - geocoding api not responding fast enough

Tags: ruby, rubygems, geocoding

***Possible duplicates:***

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093393/geocoding-api-not-responding-fast-enough-for-ip-address/), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484486/geocoder-gem-not-working-in-production-environment), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451099/using-geocoder-on-production-server), [Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451099/using-geocoder-on-production-server)

Above references are not helping me anyway!

**Code:**

```
require 'geocoder'

    begin
      Geocoder.configure(:timeout => 30)
      geo_data = Geocoder.search("any_ip_address_here")
      location = geo_data.first.data
      country_code = location["country_code"]
      puts "#{country_code}"
    rescue => e
      puts "#{e.message}"
    end
```

**Gem:**

geocoder (1.2.6)

**Error:**

***"geocoding api not responding fast enough (use geocoder.configure(:timeout => ...) to set limit)"***

I am getting this error randomly in development stage as well as in production stage. Why this is happening? even though i have done:

- geocoder default time-out from 15 to 30 seconds.
- 480 requests per day.

Am i missing anything apart from the above?
Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That happens using 3rd party services - you should move the API calls to a background job and retry upon failure.

Comment: Possible solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093393/geocoding-api-not-responding-fast-enough-for-ip-address

I hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

This is described in the README under "Geocoding Services". Create an initializer `(config/initializers/geocoder.rb)`
and add:

```
Geocoder::Configuration.timeout = 15
```

Hope this will work for you :)

Answer (score -2):

*We recommend that applications that respond to user input, and therefore are highly latency-sensitive, use the Place Autocomplete feature in the Places API (also available in JavaScript, Android, or iOS) rather than address geocoding. Place Autocomplete is optimized to be used interactively, and thus has very low latency.
Address geocoding in the Geocoding API is optimized for use with complete, unambiguous, well formatted addresses, such as delivery addresses entered into online forms, and thus has higher latency than Place Autocomplete. This is already the case with the old forward geocoder. The latency difference between Place Autocomplete and the new forward geocoder increases further, since the new geocoder has greater coverage and better result quality, but at the cost of somewhat higher latency.*

*From the Google Guys*

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/faq