# geocoding api not responding fast enough for IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

In my production server I've used the Geocoder gem. But, the following code not working in the server console.

```
Geocoder.search("192.168.1.4")
```

I've configured my `geocoder.rb` file with timeout 30 seconds.  But still it gives the error **geocoding api not responding fast enough**

Surprisingly, whenever i ran `Geocoder.search("San Francisco, CA")` it gives the result within seconds.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is an issue with freegeoip, try the following:

Enter this in your rails console:

Geocoder.configure(:ip_lookup => :telize)

Now try you search in your console.

if this works you can have your file (config/initializers/geocoder.rb)

```
Geocoder.configure(

  :timeout=>20,

  :lookup=>:yandex,

  :ip_lookup=>:telize,

  :language=>:en,

  :http_headers=>{},

  :use_https=>false,

  :http_proxy=>nil,

  :https_proxy=>nil,

  :api_key=>nil,

  :cache=>nil,

  :cache_prefix=>"geocoder:",

  :units=>:km,

  :distances=>:linear

)
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using your Public facing IP instead of the internal IP you are using?

IP address geocoding often returns results for the organization which owns the IP address block instead of the actual computer IP address. This is because IP address geocoding does not consider private IPs, VPNs, or internal network blocks.

Comment: I've used google's IP : 173.194.120.99. But still same error.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when i am not connected to the internet..pls verify that you have an active internet or you are bypassing the proxy.